# Particular css class being ignored

Tags: css

Once in a while, a css rule will be ignored, despite being correctly defined in the loaded stylesheet, and correctly targeted at a class patently present in the markup. Has anyone come across this, and can anyone explain what is going on?

You will not be able to reproduce the issue, but consider the following, pasted from markup/scss:

```css
.test-footer {
 display: none;
 background: red !important;  
}
 
.test-footer {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<footer class="test-footer"></footer>
```

The topmost rules did nothing (I added the red !important line just to be sure it wasn't being overridden). Then, without changing anything else, I added the second, identical rule, which was honoured without issue.

I have experienced this a few times now – not so frequently that it has entered my offhand list of things to look for when css misbehaves, but often enough over the last year that I have taken notice.

I am using Coda 2, and working on a mac running OSX El Capitan. Also, I am using the Coda sass plugin to compile.

The behaviour was consistent across browsers, and editing any other part of the stylesheet produced the expected results. As stated above, I checked, and the correct css was there all along – one part of it was simply ignored.

My solution should not work, so why does it? Come to that, the issue should not arise in the first place, so why did it?

Update:

I enabled hidden characters, to see if they might be the culprit, like Ruud Helderman suggested below, but I found nothing. In the end I had to let it lie. I solved my problem, after all, even though the "solution" was a magical fluke, or rather the problem was, and the question was asked as much out of intellectual curiosity as anything else. I am leaving the question unanswered for now, thinking that when and if it occurs again, I will update with any findings.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen which is not happening.. you set display:none.. so footer is not visible ..?

Comment: Like I said, you won't be able to reproduce this. In my project, that footer was visible despite the first rule: it took the duplicate rule to hide the footer.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and the sass cache that the sass pre-compiler uses?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but I think I can rule out caching. I opened the page in a different browser (with no cached version) when the problem arose, and the problem persisted. As for editor caching, that's interesting, whether it explains the issue or not. I didn't even know that was a thing, but it fits with something I've found in the past: sometimes, the editor seems to overlook a minor change when compiling scss, and I have to do something more drastic, like delete all lines in the document, save, undo, then save again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this came back in a big way – there was much griping about my perceived failure to pull changes from git, because my colleague's styling changes appeared to be overwritten when I pushed changes to the server. I found that his changes were actually present in the compiled css: they were simply ignored by the browser. I still found nothing amiss in the css – no hidden characters, nothing.

But in this case there were differences in how the scss was written, and also in how we compiled. Specifically, he uses linebreaks weirdly, which shouldn't affect the output, but did. He also uses Coda, by the way, so this makes no sense at all. But the "solution" turned out to be changing the sass output style to "compressed", which is annoying in development, and shouldn't be necessary, as the compiled css was fine all along, but it made the problem go away, and hopefully, this is the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

My only experience that comes anywhere near what you describe, is a syntax error in the stylesheet causing *all* subsequent rules to be ignored. Rules preceding the faulty rule would still be effective.

Another possibility might be the presence of an invisible character (e.g. [U+200B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)); try to configure your text editor to reveal non-printable characters.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility. I suspected it might be something happening in the editor I'm using, but as the loaded css looked right, I didn't investgate further. I'll have to experiment. Thanks!